# jQuery tools scrollable navigation dots

Tags: jquery, navigation, jquery-scrollable

http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html

My question is: how to implement scrolling not one but four elements by clicking dot. Left, right buttons should scroll one item per click.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

See this demo, it has the dots I believe you are referring to <strike>http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/site-navigation.html</strike>.

**Update 7-Jan-2016**
The link above has rotted. It's all under github now: http://jquerytools.github.io/demos/scrollable/site-navigation.html.